# Python: Clustering parts of list based on condition

Tags: python

I have a list that is an arithmic expression, for which I want to seperate the parts that are multipying and make them a seperate list within a list

```
 i.e. 
 ["4", "+", "5", "*", "6", "*", "7", "+", "8"]
 to 
 ["4", "+", ("5", "*", "6", "*", "7"), "+", "8"]
```

I thought of iterating over the list in steps of two (for i in l[1::2]), starting from position 1 (since a number precedes an arithmic expression) 
and then having a 'while' condition. However I don't know how to construct the while loop in such a way it returns my desired output.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write a [parser](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/python-parsers.html)

Comment: Do not vandalize your post.

Answer (score 2):

You have nicely tokenized input, all that remains is reading these tokens into a binary expression tree.  You can then write the tree back to the list by traversing, and when you traverse you add parens back in for multiplication.  You'll have to be careful to only add parens for the top-level node, otherwise you'll have output like:

```
["4", "+", (("5", "*", "6"), "*", "7"), "+", "8"]
```

That would be the most 'generic' way to do it.  You can see some examples in Python:
    http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Trees/ParseTree.html
    https://abhirama.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/expression-tree/

That said, here's a more direct way to process your specific case:

```
def add_parens(lst):
    last_num = lst[0]
    curr_list = None

    for character in lst[1:]:
        if character == '+':
            if curr_list is not None:
                curr_list.append(last_num)
                yield curr_list
                curr_list = None
            else:
                yield last_num
            yield character
        elif character == '*':
            if curr_list is None:
                curr_list = []
            curr_list.append(last_num)
            curr_list.append('*')
        else:
            last_num = character
    if curr_list is not None:
        curr_list.append(last_num)
        yield curr_list
        curr_list = None
    else:
        yield last_num


x = add_parens(l)
list(x)
[out]:  ['4', '+', ['5', '*', '6', '*', '7'], '+', '8']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it for you.

```
expressions_list = ['1','*','2']
mult_list = []

for i in range(1, len(expressions_list)-1):
    if expressions_list[i] == '*':
        mult_list.append(expressions_list[i-1])
        mult_list.append(expressions_list[i+1])
```

I'd create a function that takes a list and returns mult_list.

**Just realized I didn't exactly answer your question. This should get you started at least.

Comment: Thank you, yes I understand this, however this will print numbers twice and won't add the "*" sign inbetween. For example for ["4", "+", "5", "*", "6", "*", "7", "+", "8"] I will only get ['5', '6', '6', '7'], which has a 6 repeated. And its exactly this part that I don't manage to get to work!

Comment: So to get a sublist of just the numbers being multiplied, you could include a step for mult_list.append(expressions_list[i+1]). 

Another option would be returning mult_list = expression_list [i-1: i + 2]

Answer (score 0):

Totally unpythonic, no validations, bu it's work :)

```
L = ["4", "+", "5", "*", "6", "*", "7", "+", "8"]

i = L[0]
mult = ()
K = []

for sign, j in zip(L[1::2], L[2::2]):
    if (sign == "*"):
        mult = mult + (i, sign)
    else:
        if mult:
            mult = mult + (i,)
            K = K + [mult] + [sign]
            mult = ()
        else:
            K = K + [i] + [sign]
    i = j

if mult:
    mult = mult + (i,)
    K = K + [mult]
else:
    K = K + [i] 

print K
```

Comment: if you use "if mult:" what does it check for in the list? if it is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by appending the items to an inner list if they are "*" or are preceded or followed by "*". If not, the items are appended to the outer list.

```
exp = ["4", "+", "5", "*", "6", "*", "7", "+", "8"]
output = []

for before, current, after in zip([None] + exp, exp, exp + [None]):
    if '*' in [before, current, after]:
        if type(output[-1]) is not list:
            output.append([])
        output[-1].append(current)
    else:
        output.append(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good job on trying to learn Python. I have a super simple regex solution for your:

```
import re

def addBrackets(str):
    str = re.sub(r'(.\*)', r'(\1', str)
    str = re.sub(r'(\*.)', r'\1)', str)
    return re.sub(r'\(\)', r'', str)

print(addBrackets('4+5*6*7+8')) # prints out 4+(5*6*7)+8
print(addBrackets('4+8'))       # prints out 4+8
print(addBrackets('4*5*6*7+8')) # prints out (4*5*6*7)+8
print(addBrackets('4+5*6*7*8')) # prints out 4+(5*6*7*8)
```

its adds brackets around every number next to a * sign and then cleans the mess providing a clean solution.

If you dont like the three line regex solution and was looking for something more algorithmic, here it is: One for cycle, couldnt be more efficient:

```
def addBrackets(str):

    # this will store the pointer inside the string
    pos = 0

    # this will store whether we are in multiplication
    inside_multiplication = False

    # loop throught the string
    for i in range(len(str)-1):

        # meeting * sign and not being in multiplication mode will ad a bracket before the last digit
        if str[pos] == '*' and not inside_multiplication:
            inside_multiplication = True
            str = str[:pos-1] + '(' + str[pos-1:]
            pos = pos + 1

        # meeting a plus sign will break the multiplication mode
        if str[pos] == '+':
            if inside_multiplication:
                str = str[:pos] + ')' + str[pos:]
            inside_multiplication = False
        pos = pos + 1

    # dont forget to close the multiplication 
    if inside_multiplication:
        str = str + ')'
    return str


print(addBrackets('4+5*6*7+8')) # prints out 4+(5*6*7)+8
print(addBrackets('4+8'))       # prints out 4+8
print(addBrackets('4*5*6*7+8')) # prints out (4*5*6*7)+8
print(addBrackets('4+5*6*7*8')) # prints out 4+(5*6*7*8)
```

Comment: Thanks of your comment. However my input is a list of strings, could you maybe adjust your first three lines that it takes the input that I wrote down in my question? Is that possible? because the three lines look really neat!

Comment: ;-) just do ''.join(yourlist) and you have a string. no need to work with list of strings when a string is more or less a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a recursion problem. Have a look at this solution. For each multiplication this code creates an internal list which is a little bit different from your proposed solution. But, since this is just multiplication, that should not be a problem.

```
expression = ["4", "+", "5", "*", "6", "*", "7", "+", "8"]

def evaluate(expression):
    evaluated = []
    for i, e in enumerate(expression):
        if e == '*':
            new_e = [expression[i - 1], e, expression[i + 1]]
            evaluated.extend(expression[: i - 1])
            evaluated.append(new_e)
            evaluated.extend(expression[i + 2: ])
            expression = evaluate(evaluated)
            break
    return expression

print evaluate(expression)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the most readable solution

```
import copy
def intersperse(lst, item):
    i = 1
    lst_copy = copy.copy(lst)
    while i < len(lst_copy):
        lst_copy.insert(i, item)
        i += 2
    return lst_copy


def format_output(x):
    if x.find("*") != -1:
        return tuple(intersperse(x.split("*"), "*"))
    else:
        return x

x = ["4", "+", "50", "*", "6", "*", "7", "+", "8"]
x = "".join(x).split("+")
x = intersperse(x, "+")
list(map(format_output, x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you are trying to parse a (very simple) expression language into some interpretable data structure. There already exists a [set of robust algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Parsing_algorithms) to handle this kind of problem. Trying to come up with something new and cutting corners often leads to bugs. As far as I can tell, many of the answers posted here at this time have some issues in corner cases.

I'll recommend a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) since it is the most human-readable.

```
import re

class Parser(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        # iterator over tokens
        self.stream = iter(tokens)

        # current/lookahead tokens
        self.curr = None
        self.next = None

        # read in first token
        self.advance()

    def advance(self):
        # advance by one token
        self.curr = self.next
        self.next = next(self.stream, None)

    def accept(self, *tokens):
        # advance by one token if the next token satisfies
        # a filter function, or matches a set of tokens.
        try:
            matches = tokens[0](self.next)
        except TypeError:  # first argument not callable
            matches = self.next in tokens

        if matches:
            self.advance()
            return True
        return False

    # productions
    def add(self):
        # add := mul {+ mul}*
        node = [self.mul()]
        while self.accept('+'):
            node.extend((self.curr, self.mul()))
        return self.clean(node)

    def mul(self):
        # mul := term {+ term}*
        node = [self.term()]
        while self.accept('*'):
            node.extend((self.curr, self.term()))
        return self.clean(node)

    def term(self):
        # term := [0-9]+
        if self.accept(str.isdigit):
            return self.curr
        raise SyntaxError

    def clean(self, node):
        if len(node) == 1:
            return node[0]
        return node

# utility wrapper
def parse(tokens):
    return Parser(tokens).add()
```

Then, you can do something like

```
parse(list('1+2*3+4*5*6+7+8'))
# ['1', '+', ['2', '*', '3'], '+', ['4', '*', '5', '*', '6'], '+', '7', '+', '8']

parse(list('1+2*3+4*5+6*7+8'))
# ['1', '+', ['2', '*', '3'], '+', ['4', '*', '5'], '+', ['6', '*', '7'], '+', '8']
```

This is a very basic example, but it is easy to extend to handle more complicated expressions, other operations, etc.